# Azure Service Bus Hosting REST Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, azureservicebus

I am trying to host a REST service that can be relayed from the Azure Service Bus
I saw [this blog](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/07/beautiful-rest-services-urls-in-windows-azure-with-wcf4s-routing-integration-feature.html) which looks like it would answer my question but unfortunately, I get the same result.

This is the exception I receive when trying to hit the service in the browser.

> The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility.
>       ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility
>       mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the 
>       service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.

If I exclude the Azure Endpoint registration from the `ServiceHostFactory` that connects to the Azure Service Bus (*via [`basicHttpRelayBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.basichttprelaybinding.aspx)*), I do not get this error and I can hit the service locally. It has something to do with hosting both RESTful services (`webHttpBinding`) and Azure Service Bus relay bindings (`basicHttpRelayBinding`).

In the global.asax I add the service hosting

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add REST service hosting.
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("myservice/rest",
         new CustomWebServiceHostFactory(typeof(IMyService)),
         typeof(MyServiceProvider)));
}
```

I have decorated my Service Provider as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyServiceProvider : IMyService
{
    ...
}
```

The web.config for my Service Interface running in IIS has the following values:

```xml
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="standardEndpoints" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.StandardEndpointsSection, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </sectionGroup>           
</configSections>

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
       <webHttpEndpoint>
          <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
             <security mode="None"/>
          </standardEndpoint>
       </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
...
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [This post seems like the same issue](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/21944.aspx), though I don't know if using [`baseAddressPrefixFilters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924481.aspx) would resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to try my this blog which shows exact same problem along with root cause and resolution, try applying the suggestion and let us know:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/17/wcf-rest-http-application-connecting-azure-service-bus-using-webhttprelaybinding-causes-aspnetcompatibilityenabled-error.aspx